# jQuery selector $() functionality in an independent function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for an advanced function to select elements in the dom without using jQuery or any other library.

Something that will accomplish the same thing that the $(selector) function does in jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might be looking in the wrong place... you might want to try google.com, bing.com, duckduckgo.com etc

Comment: why o why ? you don't like jQuery ? you have some argument not to use it ?

Comment: I know... jQuery is the future of Javascript. But I need ti use it with a Chrome extension... I prefere to use standard functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can use is [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which allows you to select using a CSS selector, just as you would with jQuery:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('#someEl a.someClass');
```

You would then need to loop through `links` to do whatever you wanted to do to the elements. Note that a lot of jQuery-provided utility functions (e.g. `addClass`) will not be available. Some utility functions are available in modern browsers (and more will come when DOM4 is adopted) but it will be a lot clunkier than jQuery makes it. That's the price you'll pay.

Comment: Thanks ! I was looking exactly for this function.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses library called Sizzle (http://sizzlejs.com/) to handle selectors. So probably you can checkout how it does the trick.

Comment: "without using jQuery **or any other library.**".